# How to find the day with the largest traffic number in an array of weekdays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects with 2 values, name and number eg:

```
var Saturday = new Weekday (Saturday, 84);
```

*note: weekday is a prototype (not that important)*

I have 7 of these to represent all days in a week.
I need to find the one with the largest number (parameter 2)
and return the name of the week (parameter 1 eg: Wednesday).
Is there a way to do this?

If you need it here is some code:

```
function mostPopularDays(week){
    this.week= week;
    this.__proto__ = new Weekday (name, traffic);
    var name = undefined;
    var traffic = undefined;
    var Sunday = new Weekday (Sunday, 65);
    var Monday = new Weekday (Monday, 23);
    var Tuesday = new Weekday (Tuesday, 12);
    var Wednesday = new Weekday (Wednesday, 98);
    var Thursday = new Weekday (Thursday, 87);
    var Friday = new Weekday (Friday, 54);
    var Saturday = new Weekday (Saturday, 84);
}
```

Hey, here's an update, I forgot to mention that there can't be any ES6 Syntax and also the prototype for anyone who asked for it is:

```
function Weekday (name, traffic) {
    this.name = name;
    this.traffic = traffic;
}
```

Comment: Have you coded the `Weekday` class or is that from somewhere else? Answers may depend on whether you can change that. If you wrote it can you add it to the question?

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, Basically the prototype cannot be changed, I will edit this post to include the prototype function.

Answer (score -2):

Finding max objects of days within weekdays:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function(weekday) { return weekday.day; }))
```

Comment: The OP wants the name of the day.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it unfortunately is not exactly what I wanted